# Explicit connection between vector fields and derivations

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm taking course on differential geometry and I have a question that I haven't been able to find an answer to.

I understand that there are two equivalent definitions of a vector field on a smooth manifold $M$:

1. A vector field $X: M \to TM$ is a map assigning $p\mapsto X|_p$
2. A vector field $X: C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ whereby $f\mapsto X(f) \in C^\infty(M)$ and $X(f)(p) = \sum_{i=1}^n x^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)$

However, I don't understand how these definitions work on a more explict level for calculations. For example, take the vector field $X = x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + xy\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then for some $p = (x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is $X|_p$ just $x_0\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x_0y_0\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$?

I understand that this question is quite elementary, but I haven't been able to find an explicit answer in any textbooks or articles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think of a vector field as a function which assigns a bunch of vectors to behave a certain way on a manifold, and at an arbitrary point on the manifold, the behavior of a vector field is precisely like a velocity vector emanating from that point. Both of these definitions (loosely speaking) capture this exact idea.

Comment: @Nicholas James, thank you for the reply. I understand the intuition behind vector fields, but I'm a bit lost on how I can apply it to calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is YES, but you must evaluate the partial derivatives at $p$ as well. This then gives you $X(f)(p)$ when you apply it to a smooth function.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, I realize that I was missing the evaluation at $p$ step